# ASP.NET Core Web API Swagger docs incorrect with reference loop between classes

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have the following classes in my application:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid PublicKey { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
}
```

and the following API controller that just gets a list of all the people (there are always 2, and they always have 3 orders each):

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class PeopleController : Controller
{
    // GET api/people
    [HttpGet]
    public List<Person> Get()
    {
        PeopleService people = new PeopleService();

        return people.GetAllPeople();
    }
}
```

I should point out that I had issues from the start with the navigation property on the Order class referring back to the Person that owns it, as the Json.NET formatter doesn't like this out of the box and you have to configure it to ignore reference loops. I have done this in the Startup.cs like so:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(o => 
        {
            o.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None;
            o.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });

    services.AddSwaggerGen();
}
```

This works great, and when I make a request I get the following response:

```
[
    {
        "orders": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "date": "2016-10-26T17:16:35.21",
                "personId": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "date": "2016-10-26T17:16:35.21",
                "personId": 1
            }
        ],
        "id": 1,
        "publicKey": "b6a7c21c-86d8-4bb9-9a05-bd394e6ed0c9",
        "firstName": "Lauren",
        "lastName": "Phillips"
    },
    {
        "orders": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "date": "2016-10-26T17:16:35.21",
                "personId": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "date": "2016-10-26T17:16:35.21",
                "personId": 2
            }
        ],
        "id": 2,
        "publicKey": "8b5a90b4-a9a2-4a0e-96dd-529962972456",
        "firstName": "Robert",
        "lastName": "West"
    }
]
```

I am using [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) to generate Swagger docs for my API. The "Example Value" that is generated by Swashbuckle/Swagger seems to be including the Person again within each order:

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "publicKey": "string",
        "firstName": "string",
        "lastName": "string",
        "orders": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "date": "2016-10-27T14:19:52.437Z",
                "person": {
                    "id": 0,
                    "publicKey": "string",
                    "firstName": "string",
                    "lastName": "string",
                    "orders": [
                        {}
                    ]
                },
                "personId": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I don't want people consuming the API to expect the person to be included again in each order, especially as that isn't what you actually get because I configured it to ignore reference loops above. I imagine that this issue is related to the reference loop, but I am not sure. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you can use the attribute - `[JsonIgnore]` to not show that up in the swagger documentation

Comment: Thanks, that does work, but the Person will then be forever left out of orders. It might well be that at some point i need to get a specific order and expect it's Person to come with it. I appreciate that I'm being difficult, I am just starting a big project and want to work out all these things before I cause my self problems later on.

Comment: @Ben, I am not sure why you have Person object referenced in Order class again. But, if the Order object will never have Person Property when referred from the context of Person Class, then you can actually split Order into two classes - OrderBasicDetails (name can be anything which make sense) and Order. OrderBasicDetails will have all attributes except Person and Order class will be inheriting from Basic and will have the person attribute.

Comment: I though it was pretty standard in OOP to provide navigation properties between parent and child objects, it allows for very simple traversing of objects. In this case they are both entity framework entities so the reference from Order back to person actually represents the foreign key relationship